# how to pass the value from table view cell to view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have one table view with many cell.Each cell have one image and one label.And what i need is when ever user press any cell it have to go to detail viewcontroller.And there i need to show the respective image and label name in my detail view controller.How to do that.

I have done all segue.But in my detail view controller i have one image and label.Now how can i show the image and label name - when i select the any cell from my table view ??

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var valueToPass:String!
var selectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath()

    var tableData: [String] = ["Christ Redeemer", "Great Wall of China", "Machu Picchu","Petra","Pyramid at Chichén Itzá","Roman Colosseum","Taj Mahal"]
    var arrImageName: [String] = ["ChristRedeemer", "GreatWallOfChina", "MachuPicchu","Petra","PyramidChichenItza","RomanColosseum","TajMahal"]

var tableRate: [String] = ["$120", "$100", "$222","$1000","$500","$900","$2000"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) ->Int
    {
    return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         return self.tableData.count;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:CustomTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomTableViewCell") as! CustomTableViewCell

        cell.imageVW.image = UIImage(named:self.arrImageName[indexPath.row])

        cell.lblName.text = self.tableData[indexPath.row]
        cell.rateName.text = self.tableRate[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
      self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath

        performSegueWithIdentifier("DetailView", sender: indexPath)
    }


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){
        let indexPath = self.selectedIndexPath

        if (segue.identifier == "DetailView") {
            var viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailVC
            viewController.data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named:self.arrImageName[indexPath.row])!)!
            //viewController.name =  self.tableData[[indexPath.row]]
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Here is my detailvc.swift

```
import UIKit

class DetailVC: UIViewController {


    var data: NSData = NSData()
    var name: String = String()



    @IBOutlet weak var ImgView: UIImageView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.ImgView.image = UIImage(data: data)
        //self.detailLabelNamee.text = name
    }






}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your did select with something like this

Declare one gloabal indexPath in ViewContrller like this

```
var selectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath()
```

Change your didselect like this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("DetailView", sender: self)
}
```

Now in prepareForSegue method add this

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){
    let indexPath = self.selectedIndexPath

    if (segue.identifier == "DetailView") {
        var viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailVC
        viewController.data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named:self.arrImageName[indexPath.row]))
        viewController.name =  self.tableData[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

Now add two global identifier in DetailVC like below

```
var data: NSData = NSData()
var name: String = String()
```

Now assign this data and string to imageview and label in viewdid load

change the viewdidload of detailVC like this

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.ImgView.image = UIImage(data: data)
    self.detailLabelNamee.text = name 
 }
```

Hop this will help.

Comment: i am getting error that ` Instance member 'data' cannot be used on type 'DetailVC' `

Comment: But how can i assign the image, label name in my detail view controller.Because when i select any cell i need to show that particular cell image and name in my next detail view controller.Right ??..So only i did iboutlet for image ,label to my detail view controller.Now i did you solution.But its just creating a variable.How can i assign the image, label name in my detail view controller ??

Comment: Have you got the image and name in DetailVC now?

Comment: my app getting crash` Could not cast value of type 'SimpleTable.CustomTableViewCell' (0x10c9c1918) to 'NSIndexPath' (0x10d1cc438).`  In this line ` let indexPath = sender as! NSIndexPath`

Comment: Pass indexPath in didselect method of UItableview like this. performSegueWithIdentifier("DetailView", sender: indexPath)

Comment: i did ..But same crash  i am getting

Comment: `Could not cast value of type 'SimpleTable.CustomTableViewCell' (0x10c9c1918) to 'NSIndexPath' (0x10d1cc438)`

Comment: I have edited answer and add new indexPath variable globally plz check.

Comment: again i am getting new crash `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid index path for use with UITableView.  Index paths passed to table view must contain exactly two indices specifying the section and row.  Please use the category on NSIndexPath in UITableView.h if possible.'
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114209/discussion-between-nirav-doctorwala-and-mark).

Comment: Any solution please

Comment: Where you have send project file?

Answer (score 1):

In your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you can just perform the segue and in `prepareForSegue` you can get the indexPath with `self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow`. And of course it returns an optional and you have to check it first for safety. I think this is the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

In your **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** you can get the index path of the selected row  and then you can performSegue and pass index path in sender. 
In prepareForSeque , from the **index path** , you can get the image , tableData and tableRate . Which you can pass to detail view . Something like below

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    performSegueWithIdentifier("DetailView", sender: indexPath)
}



override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){
    let selectedIndexPath = sender as! NSIndexPath

    if (segue.identifier == "DetailView") {
        var viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailVC

viewController . setValues(tableData:tableData[selectedIndexPath] , rate: tableRate[selectedIndexPath] , imageName:arrImageName[selectedIndexPath])
}


class DetailVC: UIViewController {

    var imageName:String!
    var tableData:String!
    var tableRate:String!



func setValues(tableData:String , rate:String , imageName:String){
imageName = tableData
tableRate = rate
imageName = imageName

}
```

or

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){
    let selectedIndexPath = sender as! NSIndexPath

    if (segue.identifier == "DetailView") {
        var viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailVC

viewController.imageName = self.arrImageName[selectedIndexPath.row]
viewController.tableData = self.tableData[selectedIndexPath.row]
viewController.tableRate = self.tableRate[selectedIndexPath.row]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a variable for store indexpath in that .

var selectedItemIndex = Int()

on click of cell write below lines in **didselectowatndexaPath**

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        selectedItemIndex = indexPath.row
        self .performSegueWithIdentifier(“YourViewController”, sender: nil)
    }


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        let yourVC = segue.destinationViewController as! YourViewController


        yourVC.text = tableData[selectedItemIndex]
        yourVC.image = UIImage(named:arrImageName[selectedItemIndex]) 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there! The line:
performSegueWithIdentifier("DetailView", sender: self)

needs changing. 'self' is passing a reference of the current view controller to the prepareForSegue method. If you change 'self' to 'indexPath', then prepareForSegue will see the cell index path in the 'sender' object and you take what you want from that.

You could do something like:

```
if (segue.identifier == "yourSegueIdentifer") {
    var viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailVC
    let indexPath = sender as! NSIndexPath
    viewController.passedImageName = self.arrImageName[indexPath.row]
    viewController.passedData = self.tableData[indexPath.row]
    viewController.passedRate = self.tableRate[indexPath.row]
```

and in DetailVC:

```
class DetailVC: UIViewController {
    var passedImageName:String!
    var passedData:String!
    var passedRate:String!
```

Comment: But how can i assign the image, label name in my detail view controller.Because when i select any cell i need to show that particular cell image and name in my next detail view controller.Right ??..So only i did iboutlet for image ,label to my detail view controller.Now i did you solution.But its just creating a variable.How can i assign the image, label name in my detail view controller ??

Comment: i am getting this error crash `Could not cast value of type 'SimpleTable.CustomTableViewCell' (0x106060908) to 'NSIndexPath' (0x10686b438).`  under this line `let indexPath = sender as! NSIndexPath`